# Android: Text from first TextView overflow into second TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to have two separate text views where I assign a chunk of text to the first text view and have any overflow text be set to the second text view.  I do not know at build time what text will be used to populate the TextView.

The best example I can think of is similar to imagining a two page eReader where the left "page" text seamlessly flows into the right "page."

I really just don't know where to start other than some really complicated counting functions that I want to avoid.  I tried looking at some open source eReaders but that didn't really help.

How can I do this?

Comment: Build your own [Compound Controls](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound).

Answer (score 1):

You can author a custom widget that dynamically adds text views as the length of its "buffer" grows. Covering that topic is beyond the scope of what can be answered here, but here's a link to get you started,

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

That being said, I'm not sure what you mean by "i don't control the text being shown". Something is calling `setText()` on the TextView object. At the point when that happens, just have something like,

```
String text1 = ...;
String text2 = null;
if (text1.length() > LIMIT) {
  text2 = text1.substring(LIMIT, text1.length-1);
  text1 = text.substring(0, LIMIT);
}
tv1.setText(text1);
if (text2 != null) {
  tv2.setText(text2);
}
```